# Binning Pandas column of timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, time, binning

I am trying to bin a column of timestamps in a dataframe. The timestamps are of the format 0:00:00, and I think they are strings. I tried using `uber.dtypes()` but it keeps returning an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b4120eada070> in <module>()
----> 1 uber.dtypes()

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

[picture of dataframe for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCrCl.jpg)

`uber["Time"].head().to_dict()` returns the following:

```
{0: '0:11:00', 1: '0:17:00', 2: '0:21:00', 3: '0:28:00', 4: '0:33:00'}
```

When I use these bins and labels:

```
bins = np.arange(0, 25, 1)
labels = [
    "0:00-1:00",
    "1:01-2:00",
    "2:01-3:00",
    "3:01-4:00",
    "4:01-5:00",
    "5:01-6:00",
    "6:01-7:00",
    "7:01-8:00",
    "8:01-9:00",
    "9:01-10:00",
    "10:01-11:00",
    "11:01-12:00",
    "12:01-13:00",
    "13:01-14:00",
    "14:01-15:00",
    "15:01-16:00",
    "16:01-17:00",
    "17:01-18:00",
    "18:01-19:00",
    "19:01-20:00",
    "20:01-21:00",
    "21:01-22:00",
    "22:01-23:00",
    "23:01-24:00"
]

uber["Hour"] = pd.cut(uber["Time"], bins, labels = labels)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

If I change the bins to:

```
bins = str(np.arange(0, 25, 1)
```

I get this error:

```
AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

I realize I could probably convert these to seconds and us pd.to_numeric() to convert the column to integers so they can be binned, but I've poked around the documentation and am still unclear on how exactly to do so using datetime or time (I could do it the long way and multiply by seconds and minutes).

1) How could I convert these timestamps to seconds using datetime or time?

2) Is there a way to bin these without converting the timestamps to seconds?

I have also tried converting the values in uber["Time"] to datetime.time objects and inserting them in a new column ["Time Object"] before binning:

```
for i in range(len(uber["Time"])):
    uber.loc[i, "Time Object"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(uber.loc[i, "Time"], "%H:%M:%S").time()
```

If I try to bin using the ["Time Object"] column:

```
uber["Hour"] = pd.cut(uber["Time Object"], bins = 24, labels = labels)
```

Then I receive this error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'
```

If I try to bin using the hour of the ["Time Object"] column:

uber["Hour"] = pd.cut(uber["Time Object"].hour, bins = 24, labels = labels)

I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Comment: There should be a better way. How about you do `uber["Time"].head().to_dict()` and paste your output here? It'd be mighty helpful.

Comment: try df.dtypes instead

Comment: I pasted uber["Time"].head().to_dict() output and also the output when I try df.dtypes()

Comment: dtypes without round brackets

Answer (score 2):

You can try of taking minutes and bin to it

```
uber = pd.DataFrame()

labels = [str(i)+':01-'+str(i+1)+':00' for i in range(59)]    
uber['Time'] = {0: '0:11:00', 1: '0:17:00', 2: '0:21:00', 3: '0:28:00', 4: '0:33:00'}.values()
uber.Time = pd.to_timedelta(uber.Time)
pd.cut(uber.Time.dt.seconds/60,bins,labels=labels)
```

Out:

```
0    10:01-11:00
1    16:01-17:00
2    20:01-21:00
3    27:01-28:00
4    32:01-33:00
Name: Time, dtype: category
Categories (59, object): [0:01-1:00 < 1:01-2:00 < 2:01-3:00 < 3:01-4:00 ... 55:01-56:00 < 56:01-57:00 < 57:01-58:00 < 58:01-59:00]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "try of taking hours and bin to it"? Do you mean: in this case my dataframe is uber, so I would take uber.time.datetime.hour and cut, using the bins I pasted in the original question?

Comment: `uber["Hour"] = pd.cut(uber["Time"], bins = 24, labels = labels)`  returns `TypeError: must be str, not float`.  `uber["Hour"] = pd.cut(uber["Time"].datetime.hour, bins = 24, labels = labels)` returns `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'`.  I also tried converting the ["Time"] column to a datetime object, and when I try to bin that I receive the following: `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'`

Comment: Hi @Christina , I just edited my response according to your input